# Nonlinear forecasting

Tags: time-series, forecasting, excel

I'm working with time series data (which fluctuates constantly) and currently have 27 data points to forecast with. Would anyone be able to recommend a nonlinear forecasting method using formulas to help me predict the next 12 months?

I have looked at y=(c*LN(x))+b where c = =INDEX(LINEST(known_y's,LN(known_x's)),1) and b = =INDEX(LINEST(known_y's,LN(known_x's)),1,2)
- Is this method appropriate? It seems to produce a linear forecast which I don't think is correct.

Also, what validation methods can I use to ensure my forecast is reliable?

Comment: It is unclear what you are asking since you mention "nonlinear" forecasting in the title while you give an example of linear regression in your question. What do you mean by "nonlinear forecasting"? What is your data? What do you want to achieve?

Comment: @Tim my data is arrears percentage for the business and I need to ofrecast the next 12 months performance based on the last 27 months performance. I suppose I'm not entirely clear what method I should be using and am clearly getting this wrong!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I very much recommend [this free online forecasting textbook](https://www.otexts.org/fpp/). In forecasting monthly data (which I presume exhibit seasonality), [this section on seasonal exponential smoothing](https://www.otexts.org/fpp/7/5) should be helpful.

You can use the `ets()` function in the `forecast` package for R, which will fit an exponential smoothing model in a state space framework.

For validation, use a holdout sample. [Chapter 2](https://www.otexts.org/fpp/2) in the textbook has some information on this.

Comment: Thanks Stephan - I'll give this a read and hopefully gain some insight into what it is I need exactly!